# NavigationController in TabBarController ignores topLayoutGuide when hiding status bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, uistatusbar

I have a simple test app setup like so:

UITabBarController ---> UINavigationController --->[root to]---> UIViewController

[image: Storyboard setup]

The purple bar is simply just a UIView with a button inside it. Constraints on this view are:

[image: Constraints]

Code inside ViewController to *toggle* the status bar via the button:

```
@IBAction func updateStatusBar(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    })
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
   return !UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}
```

- All controllers in the storyboard have "Under bottom bar" and "under
  top bar" selected.
- NavigationBar is set to isTranslucent = YES

**The problem:**

With this particular setup, when the status bar re-appears/slides down, the purple UIView is not adjusted accordingly (topLayoutGuide) and doesn't move downwards with the status bar, ending up like this:

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [giphy.com](https://i.giphy.com/l0HlHuhMoLp2JhAvC.gif))</sub>

And then it tries to catch up and gets all weird and offset. I **can** prevent this from happening if I call force updates inside the animation block:

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout();
self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
```

But surely I shouldn't have to be forcing this.

- isTranslucent = false DOES fix this, but I want a translucent nav bar.
- **This weird behaviour *doesn't* happen if I remove the TabBarController**

Here is the behaviour I EXPECT/want to have:

[image: How it should look]
<sub>(source: [giphy.com](https://i.giphy.com/3o7TKVhqpQh1KPCG5y.gif))</sub>

Any ideas? Is this a bug overlooked by Apple devs or am I using the framework incorrectly?

Comment: Looks hard to predict what the effect will be of the implementation of `prefersStatusBarHidden`.

Comment: By that I mean what if the framework wants to check if the status bar is in the right state: `prefersHidden == isHidden`? Nope, never

Comment: @Andreas The logic in my code example was mostly for demonstration purposes so the toggle button would work with minimal code. In my production app, I have this set to TRUE (so its always hidden by default) and the same issue occurs.